# footers html content is not getting printed in wicked_pdf + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf to generate pdf for my rails application. 
I am trying to render a dynamic html content at the footer of my generated pdf.

I have implemented following code in controller:

```
 #app/controllers/receipts_controller.rb
  def generate_receipt
    html = render_to_string(:action => 'print_receipt', 
            :layout => false)       

    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html,
      :encoding => 'UTF-8',
      :page_size => 'A4',
      :orientation => 'Portrait',
      #:footer =>  { :content => "This is my footer content."},
      :footer => { :html => { :template => 'footer.html.erb' } } )
      send_data(pdf, :filename  => get_file_name, :disposition => 'attachment')
  end
```

If I use just the static content(check the above commented section) then it works as intended. 
But it's unable to load the footer content from the provided template location.

my footer resides at :

```
#app/views/receipts/footer.html.erb
 <div class='rec-foot'> This is my footer content (this is dynamic) </div>
```

This is how I have my print template:

```
#app/views/receipts/print_receipt.html.erb
  <htmL>
    <head>
      <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "wicked_pdf" %>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!--- my pdf page content goes here -->
     </body>
   </html> 



# app/assets/stylesheets/wicked_pdf.css
   .rec-foot{
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Issue : footer section is not getting rendered for the dynamic html content.

Comment: Maybe try the full path? e.g. receipts/footer.html.erb or even app/views/receipts/footer.html.erb

Comment: Not needed actually. because when I provide any invalid path then it shows the recognized path upto views, like 'app/views' . 
So, I interpret as I need to add further bills/file_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `:template` won't work for you because you are using `pdf_from_string` (source: the commented-out lines near [footer notes](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#advanced-usage-with-all-available-options).)

We went with `:content` by doing something like this in our app/models/pdf_builder.rb:

```
:footer: {
  content: { footer_html }
}
```

Then defined:

```
def footer_html
  ERB.new(pdf_template).result(binding)
end

def pdf_template
  File.read("full/path/of/your/file.html.erb")
end
```

We initialize in app/models/pdf_builder.rb with any of the info we need dynamically populating in /app/views/pdf_footer.en.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

you can directly add your file to the `render_to_string` method provided by the `rails`.
for ex. `:footer: {
  content: render_to_string('pdf_footer.html.erb', layout: 'pdf_layout.html.erb')
}`

`wicked_pdf` overrides `render_to_string` method so it supports its all default options as well.